# Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using the Powershell in the Azure Portal.
Terraform version =  v1.0.3
Powershell version = 7.1.3

this is my code

```
provider "azurerm" {  
  features {}  
}  
resource "azure_storage_account" "lab" {  
    name                        = "newbloddystoragegroup"  
    resource_group_name         = "TFResourcegroup"  
    location                    = "eastus"  
    account_tier                = "Standard"  
    account_replication_type    = "LRS"  
}  
resource "azure_storage_container" "lab" {  
    name                        = "blobcontainer4dev"  
    storage_account_name        = azure.storage.account.lab.name  
    container_access_type       = "private"  
}  
resource "azure_storage_blob" "lab" {  
    name                        = "TerraformdevBlob"  
    storage_account_name        = azure_storage_account.lab.name  
    storage_container_name      = azure_storage_container.lab.name  
    account_replication_type    = "Block"  
}  
resource "azure_storage_share" "lab"{  
    name                        = "terraformdevshare"  
    storage_account_name        = azure_storage_account.lab.name  
    quota                       = 50  
}
```

but when I run terraform init..I get the following error

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/azurerm...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/azure...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.74.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v2.74.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azure: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure
│
│ Did you intend to use terraform-providers/azure? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/azure, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

I've run this..

```
terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure]
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]
```

but I don't know what I have to change

What I've tried ...

1. I've put

```
provider "azurerm" {  
  features {}  
}
```

into its own provider.tf file...but I'm still getting the error

2. I've tried to put

```
provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" {  
  features {}  
}
```

...but it turns out that that is unacceptable syntax

3. I've tried replacing

```
provider "azurerm" {  
  features {}  
}
```

with

```
required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.74.0"
    }
```

..but that didn't work either

..any help is gratefully received....just guide me ..you don't necessarily  need to tell me the answer

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have gotten this error because you used `azure_*` resources

If you open [Azure Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) documentation you will figure out that all resources names start with `azurerm_*` prefix.

Comment: Aha...you are quite right!  .....I couldn't see the wood for the trees.....I'm a newbie I'm afraid.....thankyou for your respectful reply...it means a lot